# Registry Key disappearing on reboot after added to read application and services logs via WMI

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019, windows-event-log, windows-registry

I have a Windows Server 2019 VM and am trying to collect some specific Windows Event Logs using `Get-WmiObject`

In order to read an Event Logs channel in Applications and Services, I created a registry key and configured it similar to how this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616483/how-to-read-applications-and-services-logs-via-wmi) describes the process.  This worked, but when server reboots, the registry key I created disappears.  This happens on a brand new image, so I can't tell if there is something specific that is rewriting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\` on a reboot or something else.  I haven't been able to locate any documentation which would give the answer.  Is there something I can adjust or a standard pattern to recreate the keys on boot?

Thanks!

Edit: This is specifically for Windows Defender so the sub key that get's created is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational`

This works well, but when the machine reboots, it disappears.  In order to use `Get-WmiObject` you must create this key to collect events.  It isn't a customer event I am making, just using the OOB windows ones in the "Applications and Services" section.

Comment: What's the exact registry path that you are creating? I've only created keys directly under "eventlog", not with the "analytic" or "operation" sub folder like described in the post you referenced. That has always worked. You may be missing some required registry values.

Comment: You can also try to download EventSentry Light (https://www.eventsentry.com) which has a built-in tool to create custom event logs. That has always worked for me as well in the past. If that works then you can just uninstall it after, although you will probably like that tool anyways if you work a lot with event logs.